# Custom GridView doesn't display data

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, gridview

I am trying to feed my custom GridView with data fetched from Facebook Graph API. This data is a list of Album objects containing the picture for the album of the current user and the name of the album.
Fetching data doesn't represent a problem since I can see it in the LOGCAT.
What seems to be a problem is my GridView Adapter I suppose, the program doesn't give any particular error and this makes me confused.
Note that the MainActivity which will not be displayed here serves only to connect a user via Facebook account (there is no problem in this Activity)
Here is my different classes :
**----LoggedInActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LoggedInActivity extends Activity {

    String name, surname, ID;
    TextView nameOfUser;
    Button logout;
    GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;
    List<Album> albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle inBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        name = inBundle.getString("name");
        surname = inBundle.getString("surname");
        ID = inBundle.getString("ID");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);
        nameOfUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        nameOfUser.setText(name + " " + surname);
        logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGridView);

        albumList = getAlbums();
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                Intent login = new Intent(LoggedInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(login);
                finish();
            }
        });


        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getBaseContext(), albumList);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
}
    public List<Album> getAlbums() {


        albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/albums",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    Album album = null;
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        JSONObject jsonDATA = response.getJSONObject();
                        JSONArray data = jsonDATA.optJSONArray("data");
                        for(int i = 0 ; i< data.length(); i++){
                            try {
                                JSONObject e = data.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = e.optString("name");
                                JSONObject picture = e.getJSONObject("picture");
                                JSONObject dataOfPicture = picture.getJSONObject("data");
                                String url = dataOfPicture.optString("url");
                                album = new Album(name, url);
                                albumList.add(album);
                                Log.d("Mine",name + url);
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problem with JSON parsing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "picture,name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

        return albumList;
    }
}
```

------Album.java

```
public class Album {
    public String album_name;
    public String album_image;

    public Album(String album_name, String album_image) {
        this.album_name = album_name;
        this.album_image = album_image;
    }

    public String getAlbum_name() {
        return album_name;
    }

    public String getAlbum_image() {
        return album_image;
    }

    public void setAlbum_name(String album_name) {
        this.album_name = album_name;
    }

    public void setAlbum_image(String album_image) {
        this.album_image = album_image;
    }
}
```

**-----GridViewAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;


public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Album> albumList;
    private Context context;
    public GridViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Album> objects) {
        this.albumList = objects;
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return albumList.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Album getItem(int position) {
        return albumList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
        }
        Album album = getItem(position);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);
        TextView description = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.albumDesc);
        try {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((new URL(album.getAlbum_image())).openConnection().getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Problem with input output streams", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        description.setText(album.getAlbum_name());


        return v;
    }


}
```

**------item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageHolder"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="photo"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/albumDesc"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageHolder"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**------Activity_logged_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ichou.facebooktest.LoggedInActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/intro"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="username"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="logout"
            android:id="@+id/logout"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
        android:layout_below="@+id/intro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

write your code like in adapter below...
you do wrong line in inflate layout in `getView()` method

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,convertView, false);
        }
        Album album = getItem(position);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);
        TextView description = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.albumDesc);
        try {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((new URL(album.getAlbum_image())).openConnection().getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Problem with input output streams", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        description.setText(album.getAlbum_name());


        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me! The gridView still doesn't load. By the way convertView in your code should be casted to (ViewGroup).